# Why does UI refresh in different order cause a where condition?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs

I work with NodeJS/Express and React.

I have a problem with my UI caused by a request.

I have a website that shows many recipes, and I can either search a recipe by name with a search bar, or select some recipes by their categories. These 2 are managed by the same request :

```
 getAllPaginated: async (
    startIndex,
    endIndex,
    limit,
    page,
    tag,
    nameRecipe
  ) => {
    let whereConditionTags = {};
    let whereConditionName = {};

    if (tag) {
      Array.isArray(tag) && (whereConditionTags = { name: { [Op.in]: tag } });

      !Array.isArray(tag) &&
        (whereConditionTags = { name: { [Op.startsWith]: tag } });
    }
    if (nameRecipe) {
      whereConditionName = { name: { [Op.startsWith]: nameRecipe } };
    }
    
    const recipes = await db.Recipe.findAll({
      include: [
        Ingredient,
        { model: User, as: "creator" },

        { model: Tag, where: { ...whereConditionTags } },
        Comment,
        { model: User, as: "reactionUser" },
      ],

      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      where: {
        ...whereConditionName,
      },

      offset: startIndex,
      limit: limit,
    });
    return recipes.map((r) => new RecipeDTO(r));


  },
```

The problem come from "{ model: Tag, where: { ...whereConditionTags } }".
When I keep this condition and post a comment or a recipe, the page refreshes but with my comments in another order, the categories order change too...

If I remove it, all works fine.

Can someone can tell me whence this thing come from ? Thank a lot !

As a fix I tried 2 separate requests, but i also need to absolutely pass a data in the where condition too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but try a bit more specific order, like this:

```
order: [
         ["createdAt", "DESC"],
         [{model: Tag}, "createdAt", "DESC"]
       ],
```

I guess because of unsorted data from table Tag makes your requests different time after time.

Comment: order: [["createdAt", "DESC"],
      [{model: Tag}, "createdAt", "DESC"],
      [{model: Ingredient}, "createdAt", "DESC"],
      [{model: Comment}, "createdAt", "ASC"]
    ],

I just changed all like that and it work fine, thank !